# Can "Got" be used instead of "Do you have"?

Tags: conversational-deletion

> Jeff Kramer: Got any green beans?
>
> Counter Help: Sure do. Nice and fresh. Do you want mashed potato or French fries?

[Source](http://studopedia.org/9-11461.html).

I guess in the above context "Got" means "Do you have". Am I right? If so, is that usage of "Got" common in English?

And I think in the above context "Sure do" means "Sure we do". Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Got** as used in your example is very commonly used in AmE, it has the meaning **do you have**

A very famous ad campaign by the US dairy industry used the **tag line**

> **Got milk?**

**Sure do** means **of course we do** or **you can bet we do**, its feeling is a bit more playful and informal than a business like **yes we do**

The combination of **got** and **sure do** would possibly place this conversation in the **Midwest region** of the US.

**Got** also has the meaning of **understand**

> P1: Did you **get** what he said?
>   P2: Yeah, I **got** it.

means **yes I understood what he said**. This meaning is in **common usage today** and was used extensively by the **[est](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erhard_Seminars_Training)** movement in the 1970's.

All these examples are very **colloquial** and **common plain speak**.

Comment: This is correct, but it's worth pointing out for the ELL audience that this usage is very informal, and not appropriate for things like thesis papers.

Comment: @ThePhoton +1 have edited my answer to add an example and include your comment

Answer (score 3):

It's a colloquial omission.
The question is ***Have you*** got any green beans?

*Do you have any....?* or *Have any...?* are also possible.

Colloquial omissions are often used in English. Other examples include:

> <sup>1</sup> ***(Do you)*** Need a hand?
>   <sup>2</sup> ***(Have you)*** Been looking for this?
>   <sup>3</sup> ***(I)*** Can't do it.